# Allowing a function to be accessed/overriden by subclass but not any other class in same module in swift

Tags: ios, swift, oop, access-modifiers

```
class MyClass {
    func sampleFunction() { }
}
```

Suppose, I have a class and I want the method in it to be accessed/overriden by any of it's subclass but NOT by any other class in the same module. There is no such access modifiers available in swift which fulfills this requirement. In that case how can I achieve the same.

Comment: I am confused by this,  are you saying you do not want to extend it with an extension?  How does one override a method by any other class?  Unless you mean only 1 level of subclass, and not a subclass of a subclass?

Comment: Module? What is that in this context?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I have updated my post. What I want exactly is to access the method in subclass only (where I can also override that) but If I make an instance of MyClass in any other class, that method should be un-accessable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you are trying to do.  As Matt said, you need to mark it as file private.

If you have multiple classes in multiple files,  then you need to do it through an extension.  There is one caveat though,  it has to be declared @objc.

```
//file X.swift
class X
{

}
```

---

```
//file Y.swift
class Y:X{

}
```

---

```
//file X-Extensions.swift
fileprivate extension X
{
    @objc func doit(){}
}

fileprivate extension Y{
    @objc override func doit() {

    }
}
```

---

```
//file Z.swift
class Z{
    let x = X()
    func doit(){
        x.doit()   //syntax error, doit not found for instance x 
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case as well I need to all the extensions in same file

Comment: Correct,  you do not have a lot of options here

Answer (score 0):

Make it `fileprivate` and put all other classes that need to see it in the same file.

(You are trying to implement something like `protected` but Swift has no such access rule.)

Comment: Yes, I tried that but doesn't sounds like a solution to me because there may be multiple subclasses and I can't put all of them in one single file